# ReactJS. вынос компоненты из директории src

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// project/site/package.json:
"my-comp": "file: ./../../utilites/slick"

// project/site/src/App.js
import {Slick} from "my-comp/Slick"

// project/utilites/slick/Slick.js
// UPD 1: это просто мой файл с компонентом, а не полноценный npm пакет
export function Slick () {
    return test123
}
```

Имеем:
проект на ReactJS, в нем естественно `package.json`, есть файл который импортирует компоненту вне проекта, и это все работает.
Однако, если `function Slick` переписать под `const Slick` ( чтобы наслаждаться синтаксисом компонент ), то все падает

```
// project/utilites/slick/Slick.js
// Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled..
export const Slick = () => {
    return <div>test123</div>
}
```

Может кто помочь советом, желательно подробным, что в моём коде поправить, или, есть ли какой то другой способ импорта компоненты?

p.s.
[гуглил](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory) , и по теме уже много перекопал, но натыкаюсь на проекты которые выдают ошибки при установке, или нет достаточного описания что делать, или идут какие то правки в jest/ts_config, которых нету у меня в проекте

UPD 2: есть видос на ютубе от индуса, про вынос компоненты выше директории src, но там придётся прописывать абсолютный путь к компоненту, что наверно прикольно для видео, но не для реального проекта

UPD 3: уточню, еще немного. импортировать не из директории проекта JS, я могу, и что бы избавить всех от Гугления (вдруг кому понадобится), выше привел полные URL. а вот если возвращать JSX ( о чем я и написал - ошибка ) и вот советы, как настроить проект, что бы он позволял делать импорт компонент с JSX - непонятно

Comment: `если function Slick переписать под const Slick ( чтобы наслаждаться синтаксисом компонент )`, а в чем разница?

Comment: `./../../utilites/slick` это полноценный пакет nodeJS или просто папка в которой лежит файл `Slick.js` ?

Comment: Просто файл, с нужным мне компонентом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Немного предположений:**

Ваше приложение создано с помощью `create-react-app` и при этом не сделан `eject` проекта, поэтому невозможно простым способом изменить настройки `Webpack` и `Babel`.

Я пишу ответ именно для этого случая - когда не хочется делать `eject` проекта.
В противном случае нужно сделать `eject` и конфигурировать `Webpack` на возможность импорта файлов из директории вне корня проекта и вложенных в него папок.

Следует учитывать, что создатели `Webpack` не рекомендуют делать импорты вне корня проекта, так как это может привести к увеличению размера конечной сборки и дублированию использованных пакетов `NodeJS`.

---

**Кратко об источнике проблемы:**

При сборке проекта `Webpack` не применяет плагины `Babel` к файлам, которые находятся вне корня проекта, поэтому `jsx` в таких файлах не транспилируется в `JavaScript`.

---

**Используем Craco для решения проблемы:**

[Craco](https://craco.js.org/) (Create React App Configuration Override) - инструмент для изменения  конфигурации проекта, созданного с помощью `create-react-app`. Позволяет менять конфигурации `Style`, `ESLint`, `Babel`, `TypeScript`, `Webpack`, `Jest`, `Devserver`.

Для демонстрации создадим новый проект:

```
npx create-react-app test
```

Далее установим `Craco` и плагин для него `react-app-alias-ex`:

```
cd test
npm install @craco/craco --save
npm install react-app-alias-ex --save-dev
```

В файле `package.json` в разделе `scripts` заменим `react-scripts` на `craco`

```
"start": "craco start",
"build": "craco build",
"test":  "craco test",
```

В корне проекта создадим файл `craco.config.js` с содержимым:

```
const { CracoAliasPlugin } = require( 'react-app-alias-ex' );

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAliasPlugin,
      options: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

В корне проекта создадим файл `jsconfig.paths.json` с содержимым:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "paths": {
        "widgets/*": ["d:/dev/projects/mycomp/*"]
      }
    }
}
```

В корне проекта создадим файл `jsconfig.json` с содержимым:

```
{
    "extends": "./jsconfig.paths.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
    }
}
```

В файле `src/App.js` импортируем желаемый файл:

```
import { Slick } from 'widgets/Slick';
// ...
Learn React { Slick() }
```

---

**P.S.** Все описанные действия и конфигурации взяты из документации к `Craco`, тестировал на своей машине - всё работает.

**P.P.S.** Данный ответ не был бы возможен без [статьи на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/articles/752250/), потому что когда я пытался решить Вашу проблему в день, когда Вы его задали - гугл упорно не выдавал мне никакой информации о `Craco` и это при том, что я сразу понимал откуда растёт корень проблемы, а эта статья вышла спустя 2 дня после Вашего вопроса.
Удачно совпало.

Comment: с Гуглом/Хабром - совпало действительно удачно. Сам в шоке. Спс!